# WPF set application to selected/focus/foreground

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm writing a program for hotkeys. It is bound to a macro button on your mouse and keyboard, and when the button is pressed, the window is launched. The problem is, when the window is launched, it doesn't have focus. Whatever application I was in when I pressed the button to launch it, still has focus.

I need the program to have focus, as it has hotkeys inside the program and is always on top. It's a pain to have the user try and click on the small window just to gain focus.

I have tried

```
        frame.Activate();
        frame.Topmost = true;
        frame.Focus();
```

but none will bring focus.

Comment: Need more details about your App.xaml and MainWindow.xaml, or whatever.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ue8yYz4U

Comment: Still can't understand a problem.